# Use Swagger-ui for a keycloak protected App

Tags: spring-boot, docker, swagger-ui, keycloak, springfox

I'm trying to build a user-service to access keycloak with spring-boot and the keycloak-admin-client.

**edit**: I should mention that run the service and keycloak in different docker containers, I think that might be the problem.
My AUTH_SERVER is set to keycloak:8080, and I have it to redirect to localhost in my hostfile.

**edit2:** I managed to get the token through swagger, but the user-creation still ends with a 403 Forbidden, although the exact same code works if run outside of swagger. Seems like a problem with my spring-boot or my swagger.
Stragely enough, I can get a token just fine.

I want to create a user and provide a login endpoint, where another service can login a user with username/password and get a token back.

The code for user creation works if I run it outside of swagger in a main method, and I can get a token via postman. (now also through swagger)
But with swagger-ui, I get a "403 Forbidden" when trying to create a user.
[image]

I have tried both the Postrequest via resttemplate and through the admin-cli of keycloak. 
Both work when run independently of swagger and both dont work with swagger.

```java
  @PostMapping(path = "new")
  public ResponseEntity<String> addUser(UserData userData) {
    UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
    user.setEnabled(true);
    user.setUsername(userData.getUsername());
    user.setFirstName(userData.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(userData.getLastName());
    RealmResource realmResource = getRealmResource();
    UsersResource userResource = realmResource.users();
    Response response = userResource.create(user);
    log.info("Response: " + response.getStatusInfo());
    return new ResponseEntity<>("User created with userId: " + userData.getBusinessEntityId(),
      HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

My securityconfig:

```java
  /*
   Submits the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider to the AuthenticationManager
   */
  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
  }

  @Bean
  public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
    return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/api/v1/user/admin").hasRole("admin")
      .antMatchers("/api/v1/user/vendor").hasRole("vendor")
//      .antMatchers("/api/v1/user/customer").hasRole("customer")
      .anyRequest().permitAll();
  }
```

My Swaggerconfig:

```java
    @Bean
  public Docket apiDocumentation() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
      .select()
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
      .paths(PathSelectors.any())
      .build()
      .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(securityScheme()))
      .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()));
  }

  private SecurityScheme securityScheme() {
    return new OAuthBuilder()
      .name("spring_oauth")
      .grantTypes(grantTypes())
      .build();
  }

  private SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder()
      .securityReferences(Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("spring_oauth", new AuthorizationScope[]{})))
      .forPaths(PathSelectors.any())
      .build();
  }

  private List<GrantType> grantTypes() {
    GrantType grantType = new ClientCredentialsGrant(AUTH_SERVER + "/realms/User-Service-Realm/protocol/openid-connect/token");
    return Arrays.asList(grantType);
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityConfiguration security() {
    return SecurityConfigurationBuilder.builder()
      .realm(REALM)
      .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
      .clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
      .scopeSeparator(" ")
      .useBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant(true)
      .build();
  }
```

My Keycloak settings:
[image]

Comment: How you set password for the created user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution:

I annotated the Requests in my RestController as PostRequests since thats whats specified in the keycloak docs and what makes sense.

After changing them to GetRequests, they work now.

Answer (score 0):

I could manage it to work in a client credential grant.
You may want to try it with the following configuration instead.

```
    private SecurityScheme securityScheme() {
        return new OAuthBuilder()
                .name("spring_oauth")
                .grantTypes(grantTypes())
                .build();
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder()
                .securityReferences(Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("spring_oauth", new AuthorizationScope[] {})))
                .forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/api.*"))
                .build();
    }

    private List<GrantType> grantTypes() {
        GrantType grantType = new ClientCredentialsGrant(authTokenURL);
        return Arrays.asList(grantType);
    }
```

Comment: I still get the same error. And I just noticed that I forgot to mention that I use keycloak and my user-service in 2 different docker containers.

Comment: Are you sure that the Keycloak server could be accessible from the user-service?

Comment: yeah, I managed to get a token know through swagger. I just dont use the "Authorize Button" anymore.
But the code for creating a user still doesn't work in swagger.

Comment: Could you share your project in a repository so that I could help you to check further?

Comment: By the way, what's the exception you get when calling the API above? Does the user-service client have sufficient role to manage the realm in Keycloak?

Comment: Im creating a public repo for the user-service right now. 
The user-service should have the sufficient roles, since it works outside of swagger. 
Just start the whole thing with "./run.sh"